# How to use codes inside jade ( dot syntax )

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I m using [jade](http://jade-lang.com/)'s [dot syntax](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade.md#text-only-tags) to render the HTML. Inside that template I used some code to iterate some data ( posts ). But cannot get the output, it gives an error as :

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

I know i m using the incorrect syntax to use codes inside the dot syntax method. But don't know how to correct it. The following is the code. Please note:

```
div.container.
    <div class="test">
        each post, i in posts
            <div class="cls">#{post.title}</div>
    </div>
```

Any help is more appreciable.

Comment: why are you saying `post, i` it should be just `post in posts`.

Comment: I think that is not the problem...??

Comment: Do you pass your post objects to the page? The class responsible for rendering the page should retrieve the posts and pass them on to the rendered page, so that you can access these posts.

Comment: Yea sure..passed it from the router..like `res.render('posts/index', { title: 'Posts', posts:posts});`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski..then how can i do it..?

Answer (score 3):

Jade doesn't allow for using most of its syntax, such as `each` iteration, where [plain text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/comments/) is expected, such as inside "Block Text" tags (dot-suffixed).

Currently, the `each post, ...` is being output as text content rather than being evaluated, so it isn't defining `post` (and `i`) for `#{post.title}` to succeed.

You could instead use lines of "Piped Text" to mix the HTML and jade's `each` iteration.

```
div.container
    | <div class="test">
    each post, i in posts
        | <div class="cls">#{post.title}</div>
    | </div>
```

Or, you can also use Jade's own syntax throughout:

```
div.container
    .test
        each post, i in posts
            .cls= post.title
```